# Bayesian Network produces different directions depending on order

Tags: r, bootstrap, bayesian-network

I'm trying to fit a Bayesian Network model with `bnlearn` to determine the direction that users go from different actions (i.e.: do seeds lead to joins, or joins to seeds?). The data is collected per day, so each record corresponds to one day of data. Because I thought there might be time effects, I included a lagged version of each variable in the data set as well and created a blacklist to make it so current-date variables couldn't lead to lagged versions (it doesn't make sense that an event in the future had an impact on an event in the past).

The `boot.strength` function provide me with useful probabilities about the strength and direction of the association, but I noticed some strange behavior with it. Depending on the order of the variables in my data frame, I get completely different numbers. I've provided a MWE to demonstrate.

```
library(bnlearn)
library(snowfall)
library(parallel)
compute.clusters <- makeCluster(detectCores(all.tests=TRUE, logical = TRUE))

d1 = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/christopheraden/e3cac63ae65b036d3784/raw/1f2c9178d8af6ae8f45f870d9f061e869a21feec/d1.csv", header=TRUE)[,-1]
d1[,2:13] = as.data.frame(sapply(d1[,2:13], as.numeric))
d2 = subset(d1, , c(server_date, wk1_lag_current_sub_count, wk1_lag_DAU, wk1_lag_arrangements, wk1_lag_solos, wk1_lag_seeds, wk1_lag_joins,
                    current_sub_count, DAU, arrangements, solos, seeds, joins))
```

A quick perusal of the data,

```
head(d1, 2)
server_date current_sub_count   DAU arrangements solos seeds joins wk1_lag_current_sub_count wk1_lag_DAU wk1_lag_arrangements wk1_lag_solos wk1_lag_seeds wk1_lag_joins
1  2015-09-11              2572 44365           15  2894  1271  6853                      2455       27491                   16          1898           657          3422
2  2015-09-12              2580 55848           12  3873  1371  7966                      2474       51767                   19          3705          1237          7049

head(d2, 2)
  server_date wk1_lag_current_sub_count wk1_lag_DAU wk1_lag_arrangements wk1_lag_solos wk1_lag_seeds wk1_lag_joins current_sub_count   DAU arrangements solos seeds joins
1  2015-09-11                      2455       27491                   16          1898           657          3422              2572 44365           15  2894  1271  6853
2  2015-09-12                      2474       51767                   19          3705          1237          7049              2580 55848           12  3873  1371  7966
```

So the datasets are the same, except for the order of the variables. But when I bootstrap the networks to get an idea of the probability of an edge, or the direction of that edge, the results differ greatly.

```
f1 = boot.strength(algorithm = "hc", data=d1[,-1], R=1E3, cluster = compute.clusters)
f2 = boot.strength(algorithm = "hc", data=d2[,-1], R=1E3, cluster = compute.clusters)
f1[f1$from=='current_sub_count',]
                    from                        to strength direction
    1  current_sub_count                       DAU    0.369 0.6912448
    2  current_sub_count              arrangements    0.021 0.6458333
    3  current_sub_count                     solos    0.958 0.8824781
f2[f2$from=='current_sub_count',]
                from                        to strength direction
73 current_sub_count                       DAU    0.256 0.8213628
74 current_sub_count              arrangements    0.039 0.4613839
75 current_sub_count                     solos    0.915 0.8924353
```

Why does the direction and strength of the edges matter so much as a function of the order of the variables? I don't want to use a method where the order of the variables, which is arbitrary, affects the outcome so much. Interestingly, when I use `hc()` to pick the optimal network, the same model is chosen regardless of my choice of `d1` or `d2`. Is there an approach that gives me the desirable output of `boot.strength`, but with an invariance to the order I enter the covariates?

Comment: Arrows in Bayesian networks don't represent causality, and any given joint distribution has multiple equally valid factorizations into conditional distributions (therefore different directions of arrows).

Comment: If I go with the constraint-based model generation approach, the documentation says "these algorithms learn the network structure by analyzing the probabilistic relations entailed by the Markov property of Bayesian networks with conditional independence tests and then constructing a graph which satisfies the corresponding d-separation statements. The resulting models are often interpreted as causal models even when learned from observational data (Pearl 1988)." Do I not get that benefit with score-based methods?

Comment: "The resulting models are often interpreted as causal models" -- this is a stretch which isn't really supported by the theory. Yes, people do that, but they shouldn't. Pearl has more recently (2000's) worked on inferring causality, so maybe there's something useful for you in that work.